# Calling a method from another form in task.factory.startnew()

Tags: c#, winforms, task

I am trying to call a method (`form1.Data_collection`) from another class. I need to use it in `Task.Factory.StartNew`. I saw similar questions but all of them instantiate a new form1 but I want to use the same form1 everytime.

The code I implemented:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1).Data_collection(), token1, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

The method is not static

Comment: Does the code cause a problem?  Exceptions?  What?

Comment: The code doesn't throw exceptions. The code is inside a loop so it instantiates a new Form1 every time Task.Factory.StartNew executes. There are some Form1parameters that needs to be updated every time in the loop and I lose these updates when a new form1 is instantiated . Sorry for not being clear from start

Comment: Is there another way to call the method form1.data_collection instead of this `System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1).Data_collection()`

Comment: Pass the current instance of Form1 to the class that needs to call that method. But, can you move `Data_collection()` to an *utility* class, so you don't need a Form instance to call it? Maybe as a static public method? Does this method access UI components by chance? If so, you need to BeginInvoke(). Or maybe you don't need `Task.Factory` at all.

Comment: The method can't be static and it affects other methods so I can't remove it from Form1. I need to call the method everytime I use Task.Factory.StartNew() without instantiating a new form1 everytime. I am calling it from a different class. Will begininvoke work?

Comment: I don't see where you are creating a new Form1 every time.

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1` doesn't this create a new form everytime?

Comment: I don't see the word "new" in that line.  OpenForms is a collection of existing forms.

Comment: Oh my mistake! Thank you! How can I check that form1 is not invoked by a previous thread before calling it again?Does Task.Factory take care of that?

Comment: "other threads" shouldn't be creating GUI objects.  Only the main thread should.

Comment: Is form1 a gui object? The method isn't updating the gui at all. Sorry if my question sounds dumb

Comment: Forms and Controls are GUI objects.  I was referring to your comment: `How can I check that form1 is not invoked by a previous thread`

Comment: You should clearly separate the data processing (model) and the presentation (view). You shouldn't call any `Form`'s method via `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Consider redesigning your solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am going to do that